# iPhone web (Safari or Chrome) click to view a map

Tags: ios, google-maps, web, apple-maps

From a website viewed in an iPhone, I want to make an an anchor tag that, when clicked, will take the user to a map at an address.

If the iPhone as Google Maps installed, I think it would be ideal to take them to the Google Maps.  If Google Maps is not installed, it might be better to take the user to the Apple Maps app, rather than the Google Maps web site.

What's the best way to accomplish this?  Can we query whether Google Maps app is installed from JavaScript running in an iOS web site?

Comment: You can use this to see what apps are installed https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ihasapp on ios, and use this to launch app to app store https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1629/_index.html

Comment: How would I use coacoacontrols that from a web page?  As a web publisher, I want to deliver HTML/JavaScript markup to do that.   I don't get to run apps on my web page's visitors' phones.

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't support 'checking' whether an app is installed from a website, however what you can do is use the following:

```
setTimeout(function () { window.location = "googleMapsUrlHere"; }, 25);
window.location = "appleMapsUrlHere";
```

The Google Maps URL:

```
comgooglemaps://?q=your_place_here
```

Apple Maps URL:

```
https://maps.apple.com/?q=your_place_here
```

This will try and open Google Maps and if that fails, will go on to execute the second line which should open Apple Maps.

If you are after driving directions, or more specific control refer to the Google and/or Apple reference guides for their URL Schemes.